# Achieving effect of parentheses () from cmd in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

If I type in cmd

```
(whoami & echo asd) > log.txt
```

I recieve output of both commands in the log.txt file
How do I achieve this in PowerShell? Like `(whoami ; echo asd) > log.txt"`, but what I replace parentheses with?

Comment: add the two values _explicitly_ into a new string & send that out. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent PowerShell syntax uses the subexpression operator `$()`:

```
$(whoami ; echo asd) > log.txt
```

While the `()` grouping expression means "execute this part first",
the subexpression `$()` means
"execute this first and then treat the result like a variable".

It returns the result of one or more statements. For a single result,
it returns a scalar. For multiple results, it returns an array.
Use this when you want to use an expression within another expression.
For example, to embed the results of command in a string expression.

References:

- [Subexpression operator $( )](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#subexpression-operator--)
- [PowerShell: Using Subexpressions Within Strings](https://www.pdq.com/blog/using-subexpressions-within-strings/)